# Node.js best practice for being notified when batch processing is complete

Tags: node.js

I have a batch of records to process which is read from a CSV file and then inserted into a database.

Being new to Node, I am unsure the best practice to be notified when the final insert is complete.

I have tried using the drain event of the async queue to try and track the completion. But, I am only notified that the inserts have been started since they are all running asynchronously.

Comment: why dont you show us some code?

Comment: You need to wait for all of them. If your API returns a Promise you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all of them to complete. If your API is callback based you can either decrement a counter until all is done (counter reaches 0) in the callback or convert the API to Promises and use `Promise.all()`

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided any code here's some generic solution

```
var fs = require('file-system');

var readRecord01 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fs.readFile('./some/path/record01.csv', 'utf8', function read(err, csvData) {
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      }
      else { /* INFO: Reading file successful */
         resolve(csvData);
      }
   });
});

var readRecord02 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fs.readFile('./some/path/record02.csv', 'utf8', function read(err, csvData) {
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      }
      else { /* INFO: Reading file successful */
         resolve(csvData);
      }
   });
});

var readRecord03 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   fs.readFile('./some/path/record03.csv', 'utf8', function read(err, csvData) {
      if (err) {
          reject(err);
      }
      else { /* INFO: Reading file successful */
         resolve(csvData);
      }
   });
});

Promise.all([readRecord01, readRecord02, readRecord03])
.then(csvData => {
  // foo the bar or bar the foo when all promises are resolved 
});
```

You can obviously do that in a for-loop as well:

```
var promises = [];

for(i=0;i<5;i+){
    promises.push(foobar());
}

Promise.all(promises)
    .then(() => {
        for(i=0;i<5;i+){
            // foo the bar or bar the foo when all promises are resolved   
        }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
        // handle errors here
    });
```

Here's a [good read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) on Promise.all()

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. Clears up a lot for me.