# Best/proper/cleanest syntax for a simple promise?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I am in the process of converting a large system over from a standard sequential programming which means I am planning on converting 1,500+ functions.  These are simple functions that (for the most part) do basic select/insert/update/delete on tables.

Because I am about to be duplicating SO MANY functions, I want to ensure I am making the best decisions w/ syntax and structure.

My plan so far was to create a functions file for each table in the database and to create simple promise-based functions for these CRUD operations.  I export these functions and can require the correct files (by table-name) for any route that needs to use a function on a particular table or tables.

As an example, these is my telephone.js file, which is meant to handle basic CRUD operations for the TELEPHONE table.

```
const sql = require('mssql');
const { poolPromise } = require('../functions/db');

module.exports = {

    async get (cus_id) {

        const pool = await poolPromise;
        let query;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            try {

                query = ("SELECT TEL_NUMBER, TEL_TYPE, TEL_TYPE_GENERAL FROM TEL WHERE TEL_STATUS = 'A' AND TEL_PRIMARY = 'Y' AND TEL_CUS_ID = @CUS_ID ORDER BY TEL_RECEIVED_SMS_FROM DESC, CASE WHEN (TEL_TYPE_GENERAL = 'mobile') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END, TEL_PRIMARY DESC");

                pool.request()
                    .input('CUS_ID', sql.Int, cus_id)
                    .query(query, (err, results) => {

                        if (err) {

                            reject('Query failed in get(): ' + query);

                        } else {

                            if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {

                                resolve(results.recordsets[0]);

                            } else {

                                resolve(null);

                            }

                        }

                    });

            } catch (err) {

                reject('get() failed: ' + query);

            }

        });

    }

};
```

This code works fine.  I am able to get the records I need through the applicable route file, format the records and send them into a response like so:

```
const telephone = require('../functions/telephone');

...

telephone.get(cus_id).then(function(tel_recs) {

  //do stuff w/ tel_recs

}).catch (function(err) {

  console.log(err.message);
  res.status(500);
  res.send(err.message)

});
```

I have this working...BUT is this the best way?

I don't know what I don't know so I don't know everything to ask.  I guess I am attempting to solicit general advice before spending the next 3 months replicating this code 1,500 times:

1. Any pitfalls this code is introducing.
2. Should try {} catch {} be used this way inside of a promise?
3. Is creating a separate functions file for each table the "best" way of handling a store of CRUD operations?

Comment: you could check [here](https://javascript.info/promise-error-handling) for proper error handling and my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393999/node-js-best-practice-for-being-notified-when-batch-processing-is-complete/58398036#58398036) to another question

Comment: Is the error handling not spot on?

Comment: It is - the link was meant more as a confirmation for you that you'r on the right track ;)

Comment: In regards to your functions: it often makes sense to have seperated route-files for various categories or ops, but that depends on the stucture you try to create.. Having a functions-file for each table is a bit,.. let's say hard to maintain.. I tend to write generic helper functions in some _crudHelpers.js_ file and import them when needed. Things like table-names, and all that can be passed via arguments to those 'generic funcs'..

Comment: If you'r not 100% sure what I mean I can write up an answer how I would approach your task..

Comment: iLuv, no, I understand writing generic SQL and passing in the arguments.  We have a mature application and none of the CRUD statements are similar any more.  They have strange insert behaviors, history logging, or strange ordering behaviors, etc

Comment: iLuv, I was curious about handling catch() twice as I do, w/ one try {} catch {} in the promise and then again outside of the promise after the .then.

Comment: no issues with catching in an async/await func outside the promise ;) [good read as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453683/how-to-reject-in-async-await-syntax)